# PGFPlots x-axis problem

Tags: pgfplots

I've been stumped on how to get the y-axis to turn off, but to have the x-axis have a set domain. Every time I run the two code samples, the x-axis domain is always 0->1. The goal is to set the x-axis domain to 1->10. Help?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
    domain=1:10,
    hide y axis,
    axis x line=middle
]

\draw[line width=2] (axis cs:0, 0) -- (axis cs: 1, 0);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=1,
    xmax=10,
    axis y line=none,
    axis x line=middle
]

\draw[line width=2] (axis cs:0, 0) -- (axis cs: 1, 0);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `ymax=0.1,ymin=-0.1,` or whatever you wish to have.

Comment: That seems to work. But, that is weird. It works if you put both     ymax=#, ymin=#, but not if I only have one of them. Why do I need these two parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an explanation of what happens - and the steps derived from it:

Pgfplots computes axis limits from all `\addplot` statements inside of an axis. If there is no single `\addplot` statement, it cannot do so and (currently) has no idea on how to choose the axis limits. Thus, the only way to draw an "empty" axis is to define all axis limits.

If pgfplots has an axis without `\addplot` command (as in your example), it assumes that it is empty up to custom annotations. An empty plot needs manually defined axis limits. If the axis limits are undefined or incompletely defined, it will issue a warning message in the `.log` file and will replace the limits by the unit cube. This is what happens in your case.

Consequently: either add at least 1 `\addplot` statement or define all axis limits.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much! :)